# Retrieving data in Json from URL and assigning it to a variable that automatically updates

Tags: ajax, json

I am retrieving exchange rate data via JSON.

```
// Use jQuery.ajax to get the latest exchange rates, with JSONP:
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=myidcode',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            //code here


        }
    });
```

The data from the URL looks like this:

```
{

  "timestamp": 1396738847,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.672821,
    "AFN": 57.125,
    "ALL": 102.0126,
    "AMD": 417.593001,
    "ANG": 1.78898,
    "AOA": 97.729176,
    "ARS": 8.002059,
    "AUD": 1.076317,
    "AWG": 1.785,

//..and lots more rates like this 

}
}
```

I am wondering how I can take this data so that it updates on a page assigned to a variable called data. e.g

```
data {

      "timestamp": 1396738847,
      "base": "USD",
      "rates": {
        "AED": 3.672821,
        "AFN": 57.125,
        "ALL": 102.0126,

}}
```

This may be very simple for some people but I'm quite inexperienced so just ask me any questions if you need me to clarify anything. Thanks.

Comment: You mean like, *assigning* the response to the variable? E.g. `data = json;`?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, so that each time I reload the page and view the source code, I should be able to view the updated data.

Comment: If you load the data dynamically via Ajax, then you can't see it in the source code because it's not part of the source code.

Comment: http://dynamicguru.com/currency-converter/ So I am using code from this example. If I click into view the source code and go to 'currency.js.php' I can view the data that is being retrieved from the URL but I do not understand how this is done.

Comment: Oh I see. That's just a JavaScript file loaded via a `script` tag. It is probably generated by PHP (because of the file ending). So, instead of getting the data via JavaScript, they are getting the data via a server side PHP script and simply generated JavaScript from it and include it in the page. What you are doing is different: You are querying the data with JavaScript on the client side. I'm actually not sure what your problem really is.

Comment: I am just lost how to write the code to do this. Is it something like: function(json) {
            json.timestamp;
  json.rates;
        json.base;

        }

Comment: Still don't understand what you are trying to do. If you wonder how to *access* the data you receive, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json